# Unable to run BigQuery.Jobs.query in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm constantly getting an "Access Not Configured" error despite having done everything the tutorial page has instructed.

Help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing step in the tutorial.

Where it says:

Section 1: Activate the Google BigQuery service in Apps Script

1. Create a new spreadsheet.
2. Click Tools > Script Editor... to open the script editor.
3. Click Resources > Use Google APIs....
4. Enable the BigQuery API (v2), then click OK (no API Key is required).

It's missing step 5 and 6:

1. Click on "To use the selected APIs, enable them in the Google APIs Console."
2. Turn on "BigQuery API."

Comment: Hi Fh, I've actually already done steps 5 and 6. In the left panel of my embedded image, you can see that I've turned it on.

Comment: Interesting. When I clicked on the link from within the app script console, I was brought to the console page which has my app script name as the project name rather than my real project name. When I enabled the BigQuery API here, it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

First Configured it on Google API Console
1. Go to Google API Console
2. Create New Project
3. In Services Tab Enabled a BigQuery API

then you can configured in Apps script steps that you followed